# Does Google Speech API uses Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient (MFCC) extraction features?

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Greetings StackOverflow experts,

I would like to clarify that does Google Speech API uses Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient(MFCC) feature extraction?

If so, is there any articles/ journals that says about it?

Please enlighten me.

Thank you and have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the modern systems use log-mel filterbank, not really MFCC. Google also adds noise subtraction.

You can check this paper on Google technology:

[Acoustic Modeling for Google Home](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chanwook/MyPapers/b_li_interspeech_2017.pdf)